# .Net Application update QuickBook Application information like address

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I want to update QuickBook Data like Customer Address, Invoice Address etc. through the my .Net application. I was able to get all QuickBook data through the API, but i am not getting to update QuickBook data.

Update Function

```
StringBuilder strXML = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            XmlDocument inputXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
            inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null));
            inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("qbxml", "version=\"8.0\""));
            XmlElement qbXML = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBXML");
            inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(qbXML);

            XmlElement qbXMLMsgsRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBXMLMsgsRq");
            qbXML.AppendChild(qbXMLMsgsRq);
            qbXMLMsgsRq.SetAttribute("onError", "stopOnError");

            XmlElement custModeRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerModRq");
            qbXMLMsgsRq.AppendChild(custModeRq);
            custModeRq.SetAttribute("requestID", "15");

            XmlElement custMod = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerMod");
            custModeRq.AppendChild(custMod);

            XmlElement ListId = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("ListID");
            custMod.AppendChild(ListId);
            ListId.InnerText = _listID;

            XmlElement EditSequence = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("EditSequence");
            custMod.AppendChild(EditSequence);
            EditSequence.InnerText = _editSequence;

            XmlElement Name = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            custMod.AppendChild(Name);
            Name.InnerText = "Jack Sparrow";

            string s = QuickbooksAPI.APIBase.GetQBQueryResponce(inputXMLDoc.OuterXml);

            return inputXMLDoc.OuterXml;
```

Get Request/Response function

```
RequestProcessor2 rp = null;
                string ticket = null;
                string response = null;
                try
                {
                    rp = new RequestProcessor2();
                    rp.OpenConnection("", "Stamps.com");
                    //rp.OpenConnection2("", "Stamps.com",QBXMLRPConnectionType.localQBDLaunchUI);
                    ticket = rp.BeginSession("", QBFileMode.qbFileOpenDoNotCare);
                    response = rp.ProcessRequest(ticket, strRequest);
                }
                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("COM Error Description = " + ex.Message, "COM error");                    
                    return "";
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (ticket != null)
                    {
                        rp.EndSession(ticket);
                    }
                    if (rp != null)
                    {
                        rp.CloseConnection();
                    }
                };
```

Thanks in an advance.

Comment: Post your code, post the XML request you're sending to QuickBooks, and post the XML response you're getting back. No one can help you if you don't post any details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set below request XML.

XML Format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerModRq requestID="15">
      <CustomerMod>
        <ListID>9D84-1182061418</ListID>
        <EditSequence>1481791846</EditSequence>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>addr1</Addr1>
          <Addr2>addr2</Addr2>
          <City>City</City>
          <State>State</State>
          <PostalCode>382007</PostalCode>
        </BillAddress>
      </CustomerMod>
    </CustomerModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```